# About edit summary and edit limitation of minimum characters

Tags: support, edits, privileges

I can edit my own posts successfully, without including an edit summary, and the edit limitation of minimum characters does not take effect.

Are users who have the direct edit privilege (2000+ rep) also able to edit anyone's post without limitation, just like when editing their own post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you reach 2000 rep, and obtain the privilege to [edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit), you can edit without a minimum limit and without being forced to enter an edit summary.

At this stage you also stop earning reputation for your edits.

You might also find the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) page [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) useful.